# UIActionSheet, get the clickedButtonIndex before proceeding?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, objective-c-category

What I want to do is on a UITableView, the user swipes a row to bring up the option to delete, once they press delete, then a UIActionSheet pops up to make sure they want to delete the row since it's more important than a typical row in a table.  Depending on what they press, then I can delete the data in that row from the database.  How do I get the indexPath for that row into the UIActionSheet though?  If I had a one section table, then I might be able to use the tag for that row and recreate the indexPath, but with multiple sections, how can this be done?

It seems like there could be a better way by having a categoroy or something so in my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, I can just delete the row in there.  Or is there a way to pass back the information from the UIActionSheet?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you can store the `indexPath` as a property/ivar and then present the `ActionSheet`.

When the user confirms the deletion, just remove the data (you've stored the `indexPath`!) and remove the cell from tableview (`-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `-reloadData`). Don't forget to retain/release the `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. I would not use an UIActionSheet, I would use a UIAlertView.
2. The row being "Edited" for deletion can be or is set as the selectedRow.
3. If the user selects the "Yes" go ahead and delete that row button, then you can call the

[indexPathForSelectedRow] method on the UITableView object. No need to save additional NSIndexPath objects or remember state. The TableView is already doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I cheat by setting the tag for the actionSheet = indexpath.row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        UIActionSheet *registerActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sure You Want To Delete?"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:ACTION_SHEET_DELETE_BUTTON_TITLE otherButtonTitles: nil];
        registerActionSheet.tag = indexPath.row;
        registerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        [registerActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

and then

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:ACTION_SHEET_DELETE_BUTTON_TITLE]) {

         //do deleting stuff here using actionSheet.tag as index

    }
```

}

edit: Just saw the subtlety in the multiple sections you are using. An extended UIActionSheet by adding an indexPath property to it would help in your case?

or set tag to a 'x' digit number, first half denoting the sections and the second half denoting the rows.